# How to eliminate warning in sca

Tags: fortify, fortify-source

I am new to source analyzer.These are the warnings

```
sourceanalyzer -b opmbuild -Xmx2G -cp '/vx/vom/BUILD/nightly/sfm/tot/02_16/06_00_14/linux/opm/jars/*.jar' '/vx/vom/BUILD/nightly/sfm/tot/
02_16/06_00_14/linux/opm/src/**/*.java'    
[warning]: Assuming Java source level to be 1.4 as it was not specified. Note that the default value may change in future versions.  
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file DMPSolutionDao.java    
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file DMPWaitingOperations.java    
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file DmpOperations.java   
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file EsxDmpJob.java   
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file MyAppsController.java  
[warning]: Multiple definitions found for class VOMBackup (/vx/vom/BUILD/nightly/sfm/tot/02_16/06_00_14/linux/opm/src/pkg/unix/linux/stage/opt/VRTSsfmcs/config/adm/VOMBackup.java:20:1 and /vx/vom/BUILD/nightly/sfm/tot/02_16/06_00_14/linux/opm/src/db/config/common/VOMBackup.java
:20:1).
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to set the Java version using `-version`.  This may resolve the warnings you are getting since you may be utilizing constructs that are not valid in Java 1.4.  Those warnings are important and you need to investigate the cause.  To get to the root of the issue, use `-debug-verbose -logfile opmbuild_translate.log`.  The log entries should provide you with a lot more assistance in diagnosing the issue.  If you feel that there is a valid construct that Fortify is not parsing correctly, you should contact Fortify support and provide an example.

Comment: *Comment from [Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2620113/michael):* -version prints the version of sourceanalyzer. I believe you want the -source option.